# How to display an image in my custom node

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, image

I have a custom node and I want it to be able to display an image. I know that the node has a parameter [show_preview](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html?highlight=node#bpy.types.Node.show_preview) and if you enable it, no image appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a camera preview as an image?
As your code suggests, you don't have any image selected and loaded to get a preview from.

You can use:

```
for i in bpy.data.images:
    print(i.name)
```

to verify that you actually have an image in memory.